# Python how to assert that a method has been called

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have the following test case in python.

```
class RulesTest(TestCase):

    request_length = 484
    url = "http://www.ndtv.com"

    def setUp(self):
        har_data = open('/Users/rokumar/SiteAnalysisGit/Src/hct/hct/test.har')
        self.data = json.load(har_data)
        self.rule = models.Rule(name=RULES.DNS,user=None,
            threshold=None)
        self.rule.save()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.rule.delete()

    def test_parse_har(self):
        with patch.object(rules, 'add_dns_analysis', return_value=None) as \
           dns_mock: 
            dns_mock.add_dns_analysis('test result', 'test url')
            result = rules.parse_har(self.data,[self.rule],RulesTest.url)
            self.assertEqual(result[RULES.TOTAL_REQUESTS], 484)
            self.assertEqual(result[RULES.HTML_SIZE], 241592)
            self.assertEqual(result[RULES.JS_SIZE], 1006469)
            dns_mock.assert_called_once_with('test result', 'test url')
```

The last assertion fails telling that the actual call got made. Why is python not bypassing this call.

Comment: Do you want to assert whether `dns_mock` was called, or rather `dns_mock.add_dns_analysis`?

Comment: `assert_called_once_with` is used to make sure that something not directly called by your test code gets called. In this case, though, you *are* calling `add_dns_analysis` directly. Unless `add_dns_analysis` has a side effect, you could remove the patch, the call, and the final assertion without affecting the results of the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want to check if the method `add_dns_analysis` was call by `parse_har()`:

Rewrite your test as

```
def test_parse_har(self):
    with patch.object(rules, 'add_dns_analysis', return_value=None) as \
       dns_mock: 
        result = rules.parse_har(self.data,[self.rule],RulesTest.url)
        self.assertEqual(result[RULES.TOTAL_REQUESTS], 484)
        self.assertEqual(result[RULES.HTML_SIZE], 241592)
        self.assertEqual(result[RULES.JS_SIZE], 1006469)
        dns_mock.assert_called_once_with('test result', 'test url')
```

Comment: @user567797 If you find useful that answer you should vote it and not just accept.